# Visio 2013 Export to PDF Page Size

Tags: pdf, microsoft-visio-2013

When using either the Save As -> PDF or Export -> PDF the resulting PDF is created at standard letter size pages. I'm an information architect and I used tabloid/landscape pages for my wireframes. I've been using Visio for 10+ years and have never had this problem.

I've changed both the page set-up, print set-up, fit-to-page, yada yada yada but cannot get the Saved As/Exported PDF to appear any larger than letter size sheets. Oddly, if I export the .VSD file as an XPS doc it appears the way it should as tabloid/landscape sheets.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: I tried this in my Visio 2013, when I set the Design -> Orientation to landscape and then export to PDF I get the landscape PDF size. Is this the problem you are encountering ?  Also why .VSD and not .VSDX ? Maybe you could put up a image.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the various 3rd-party PDF printers. I use PDF995 (no connection to the software owners - just a happy user).

Comment: I used Bullzip PDF Printer Free. It worked fine for me. http://download.cnet.com/Bullzip-PDF-Printer-Free/3000-2088_4-10536746.html

Answer (score 1):

I use the "Design->Size->Fit to Drawing" feature (Visio 2013). Sometimes it leaves some unwanted margins, but a fix is found here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980530